# Portable Firefox : a good option to ensure browser compatibility during a meeting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am developing a web app to be used during business meetings by users that can come with various OS and browser configurations.

The app interface is based on CSS and the jQuery library.
Since the users' configurations cannot be fully known in advance, there is a need to plan for backup solutions that are easy and fast to manage in case some users, especially Windows users, happen to come to the meeting with, say, an old version of IE that will not allow the web app to run with all its features. (NB : I am not so worried about Mac OS users running Safari and Windows users having Firefox or Chrome installed, given the automatic update features that these browsers have.)

I just came across [Portable Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and I thought that coming to the meeting with a few USB keys with Portable Firefox on them could be a good option to allow especially the old IEs users to join in, without having to go through the hassle and the risks associated with a browser installation at the beginning of the session.

Do you confirm ? Would there be anything more to do to ensure that CSS3, javascript and jQuery will be available to these "Portable Firefox users" or can I be sure they will be by default ?

Cheers.

Comment: Portable Firefox seems like a good option. There's nothing javascript, CSS or you as a developer can do about old IE. Another option would be Chrome Frame - but then you're altering this users (future) web experience, which they may not like.

Comment: Thank you Ahren for this and the Chrome Frame suggestion, which implies an installation if I'm not mistaken, hence your warning. Regarding CSS, javascript and jQuery, I realize my sentence was not crystal clear so I just edited it.

Comment: Best way is to try it out. Portable firefox looks like it's version 19 - so it'd be almost exactly the same as your firefox.

Comment: Don't forget though that the automatic update feature of Firefox and Chrome can be disabled by administrators so there is no way to ensure that a user of either browser is up to date. That and Portable Firefox may not run on all systems based on security setups.

Comment: I see, you're right, Joe W... The worst case scenario then looks like : old browser on which my app does not work + security setup preventing both the installation of a recent browser and the execution of any .exe file (e.g. FirefoxPortable_19.0.2_English.paf.exe)...

Comment: Another way since you are not using PHP is using nodejs with the awesome [appjs](http://appjs.org/). Uses Google Chrome and has almost all HTML5 and CSS3 stuff..

Comment: @Bondye : I developed my app with Ruby on Rails. Thanks for mentioning nodejs and appjs. This looks like just another field to explore later.